# Should I equip my MF gear before identifying items?

Tags: diablo-iii

I wanted to know if I should equip my MF gear in order to identify magic items in order for them to yield better results, or if the items just don't show their magic properties but they are already on the item (unlike for instance, what happens with a treasure chest)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Magic find only increases the chance of a higher quality item (Magic, Rare, Legendary) and does not affect the stats. After the item has dropped, magic find does not do anything; it's up to the random number generator from there.

Comment: `only increases the chance of a higher quality item` is that a fact?

Comment: I've heard others say this is true. I have tested this before and it proves to be true, although luck is also a factor.

Comment: @Nico When the game says "You get an item drop now." It then decides whether it's a magic/rare/legendary etc. item. If it decides that for instance it's a rare item, your magic find % has a chance (higher chance for higher %) to bump it up to a legendary of the same item level if it's possible for it to do so.

Comment: I think this particular statement ("magic find only affects the quality of the item") is a big part of the reason why people are confused about mf. You shouldn't just repeat that statement without explaining the definition of item quality in this context. The first time i heard that quote, I interpreted it as that mf makes monsters drop better magic items, but that is NOT the case.

Comment: Yes that was my fault. I apologize and I see how it can be interpreted two ways. It's the chance to bmp it up to the next level (Magic to Rare, Rare to legendary, etc) Thank you both for your comments.

Comment: *"After the item has dropped, magic find does not do anything; it's up to the random number generator from there."* - Not quite.  Blizz has stated multiple times that an item's stats are determined when it drops, before being identified.

Answer (score 11):

**[@Bashiok says](http://twitter.com/Bashiok/statuses/213474406507356160):**

> No, identifying doesn't roll items. The item is rolled when it drops. Identifying it is just the 'opening a present' ritual.

Answer (score 5):

It doesn't make a difference. Items are fully generated, server-side, the instant they drop.